# Will taking a snapshot of my RabbitMq instance on AWS harm my app prod?

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I have a django webapp using Celery, Supervisord and connected to a t2.micro rabbitmq instance. I wanted to upgrade to a t2.large but was wondering if taking a snapshot will affect anything. Orginally I had not built this set up and so I am trying to learn. Will proceeding with the upgrade only require me to switch the RabbitMQ ip address? What precautions should I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a snapshot of any form of datastore usually has a certain tax on the underlying hardware in terms of CPU and IOPS. Given you are currently running on a t2.instance, assuming you have burst credits remaining, taking a snapshot is probably acceptable, as the instance size suggest your traffic is low. Once you provisioned the new instance, setting it's connection string (IP address or DNS name of you set one through a proxy) in your Django settings should be sufficient to start routing traffic to the new instance.

Just FYI, AWS has a [hosted RabbitMQ](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/) option available which takes care of much of the heavy lifting for you :)

Comment: Thanks! This was super helpful. I as able to create another rabbitmq successfully. One problem now, all my messages are stuck on my smaller instance. Do you have any tips  or advice ?

Comment: This highly depends on your use-case. If you use RabbitMQ to just broker in-flight messages I'd just drop the old ones and move on, if they were important, you should try to replay a backup of the old instance into the new one. While I have not done this myself yet, this piece of documentation looks helpful: https://www.rabbitmq.com/backup.html